# db2 The SQL statement or command failed (Reason "Too many columns or record length exceeded.".). SQLCODE=-901, SQLSTATE=58004

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We have receiving the subject error in your UAT environment. Same query is running in production environment.

DB2 version and fixpack  are same on both db's.

Production:

```
db2inst1@uat:/home/prod> db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10053" with level
identifier "0604010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.3", "s140203", "IP23553", and Fix Pack
"3".
Product is installed at "/db2data/db2/V10.5".
```

UAT:

```
db2inst1@uat:/home/uat> db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable:
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10053" with level
identifier "0604010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.5.0.3", "s140203", "IP23553", and Fix Pack
"3".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5".
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the SQL query? Are the page sizes the same? Is the schema the same?

Comment: look in the sysixadv table for clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its was bug and after installing fixpack, bug is removed.